# No repeat selectors with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a drop-down selector and need to load other parts of the form based on selection.

I repeat this selector below a few times and need to make sure that no same options are selected. I suppose I need to run through the selected options of all mySelector and if the option is selected show some error message. Not sure how.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$('.mySelector').change(function(){
    var selectForm = '#' + $(this).val();
    $('div').next('.fLoad').load('formParts.html ' + selectForm );
});

<select class="mySelector">
   <option value="selectOne">Select one</option>
   <option value="o1">Car details</option>
   <option value="o2">Boat details</option>
   <option value="o3">Train details</option>
   <option value="o4">Bike details</option>
   <option value="o5">Sub details</option>
</select>

<div class='fLoad'> </div>
   <option value="selectOne">Select one</option>
   <option value="o1">Car details</option>
   <option value="o2">Boat details</option>
   <option value="o3">Train details</option>
   <option value="o4">Bike details</option>
   <option value="o5">Sub details</option>

<div class='fLoad'> </div>

<select class="mySelector">
   <option value="selectOne">Select one</option>
   <option value="o1">Car details</option>
   <option value="o2">Boat details</option>
   <option value="o3">Train details</option>
   <option value="o4">Bike details</option>
   <option value="o5">Sub details</option>
</select>

<div class='fLoad'> </div>
```

Comment: your HTML looks funky: the option tags aren't closed...

Comment: Current code with just one selector works without closing option. HTML does not require closing. But sure, I can close. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: IDs have to be unique in a HTML document. The event handler will only be added to the first element with ID `mySelector`. `next('#fLoad')` selects the next element if it has ID `fLoad`, but you only have elements with *class* `fLoad`.

Comment: Good catch! I'll update. I am trying to copy the single functionality multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a dictionary of values to bools, that way you only have to loop over the options once.

```
var alreadyUsed = {};

$("select").each(function(){
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    if(alreadyUsed[thisVal]){
        // found a dupe
    }

    alreadyUsed[thisVal] = true;
});
```

Comment: This sounds interesting. Do I add this within my $('.mySelector').change(function(){ function?

Comment: If you want to do the check each time they change one, sure.  Otherwise attach it to the submit button or whatever.  You might want to add a default "Select one" value or something and ignore any selects that haven't been changed yet, otherwise you'll get the error right off the bat